# Why does git insist my changes are local when the origin changes, causing me to not be able to pull changes?

Tags: git, branch

Here is the scenario:

1. I clone the staging branch of my codebase:

   ```
   git clone -b staging git@my.giturl.com:/my-repository.git .
   ```
2. I make a change elsewhere and push it to the origin
3. I attempt to pull my changes to my checkout:

   ```
   git pull origin
   ```

The previous statement fails giving me this:

```
Updating 7bb2dae..f711fb0
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    sites/all/modules/broker_auth/broker_auth.module
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

broker_auth.module is the file I changed elsewhere, but locally nothing has been touched. Why does it say it has changed? The only way I can fix is to do the following (which takes a while, perceivably because it's redownloading the entire repository)

```
git reset --hard
git pull origin
```

Is it really required that I do a reset in this situation? I feel like I'm managing my branches incorrectly but I'm having trouble figuring out what is happening.

Comment: What happens if you run `git pull origin staging` instead of just `git pull origin`?

Comment: @manojlds I make a change on my development machine, commit it, and push it. the "staging" instance in question is a unix box I am ssh'd into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the cause of my issue. It ended up being my server was changing the permissions of my files so all the files were being marked as modified. I ran the following command `git config core.filemode false`, which essentially ignores filemode changes, and now my fetches work first time everytime. Hope this helps someone having similar issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can work around this problem by stashing your local changes before pulling, and reapplying them afterwards:

```
git stash
git pull
git stash apply
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you simply have a file that is being changed by your environment or IDE before you are getting a chance to merge.

If you are certain that the changes are not what you want then all you need do is simply checkout that file (your reset will also work)

i'd suggest the following workflow instead... (assuming master branch)

```
git fetch (rather than a pull, which is a fetch and a merge)
git merge origin/master (assuming you are in the master branch)
....Fails here with your message....
git checkout sites/all/modules/broker_auth/broker_auth.module (to reset the file)
git merge origin/master (so you already have the repos, no need to hit the remote again)
```

Comment: this works, and is a bit faster than my current method of using git reset --hard, but I'm still confused at why it's happening in the first place. the environment I'm doing the "git pull origin" is on a remote box I am ssh'ing into. this doesn't just happen with one file but even if I make 20 changes, those exact 20 files are always the ones preventing me from updating. it's as if it's reading the changes from the wrong location.